# Uploading High res images in android

Tags: android, android-image, android-networking, uploading

Hi I wanted to upload high res images to my php server.Right now i am sending images to my server using encoded string.Problem here is i can not upload high res image it leads me to Out of memory. My image is around 1-2 Mb large in size. Here is a snippet how i upload image to server.

```
String encodedPagerpath="";
                if(!FILE_PAGER_PATH.equals("") && FILE_PAGER_PATH.length()!=0)
                {
                    byte [] b=imageTobyteArray(FILE_PAGER_PATH,150,150);
                    if(b!=null)
                    {
                        encodedPagerpath=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        if(encodedPagerpath==null || encodedPagerpath.equals("")){
                            encodedPagerpath="";
                        }
                    }
                }

//Convert image into byte array
    static  byte[] imageTobyteArray(String path,int width,int height)
    {   byte[] b = null ;
    if(!path.equals("") || path.length()!=0)
    {


        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inDither=true;//optional
        options.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;//optional

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        bm=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,options);


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
        b= baos.toByteArray();
    }
    return b;
    }

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

I am sending this encoded string in json object. Is there any better approach i can go for? If i go beyond 150X150 it leads me to OOM. I want to upload high res image file without loosing its quality.

Comment: Don't upload big images as base64, but rather send byte array: open an outputstream to your server, open the input stream to your bitmap, then while you read chunks of data from inputstream, write them to the output stream. In this way the size of the bitmap doesn't matter. I've sent this way a 60MB image.

Comment: @gunar can you paste a sample code for that? and do i need to upload image separately?rather than putting it in a json object?

Comment: The internet is full of that: google for `"android post bitmap byte array"`. Don't send json as you would be forced to use base64 that way. Make an API on server side that knows to handle "image/*" content-types.

Comment: @gunar what is multipart upload? will that serve my purpose?

Comment: A multipart makes sense if you're sending mixed data: ex.: byte array and json, xml and text or: xml, json, byte array & text.

Answer (score 1):

I have used MultipartEntity from Apache Commons library (httpmime.jar) in my POST request to upload picture file:

```
public static HttpEntity createMultipartBody(File file) throws IOException{
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart(key, new FileBody(file));
    return entity;
}
```

Then create simple HttpPost, set Entity to it and send it to server:

```
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(SOME_URL);
httpPostRequest.setEntity(createMultipartBody(SOME_FILE_TO_UPLOAD));

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPostRequest);
```

Comment: can you elaborate it more i am new bee to this.!

Comment: What exactly you want to clarify?

Comment: I was asking for tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, I have no full tutorial - it's a part of my project and I cannot publish all related classes and functionality. I've posted all cornerstone moments in my answer - it's enough to implement this feature.

Comment: What would the PHP part look like, I had this code, but I'm doing something wrong on the server side, since it's storing 0 bytes