# Unable to upload a 10+ second video file - Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform

I have got a weird issue with Parse Server Android SDK, if I record a video shorter than 10 seconds with my device and upload it to my Parse database, it works fine.
Video files longer than 10 seconds give me this error message:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile**

Here's my code:

```
 // Create ParseObject
          final ParseObject vObj = new ParseObject(Configs.VIDEOS_CLASS_NAME);

          pd.setMessage("Please wait until your video is uploading...");
          pd.show();

          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_TITLE, titleTxt.getText().toString());
          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_IS_REPORTED, false);
          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_COLOR, colorNr);
          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_VIEWS, 0);
          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_USER_POINTER, ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_CATEGORY, selectedCategory);

          // Saving block
          vObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
              @Override
              public void done(ParseException e) {
                  if (e == null) {
                      Log.i("log-", "DATA SAVED! - SAVING THUMBNAIL...");

                      // Get video thumbnail Bitmap and save it
                      try { thumbnailBm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(SubmitVideo.this.openFileInput("imagePassed"));
                          Log.i("log-", "THUMBNAIL BITMAP: " + thumbnailBm);

                          // Save video thumbnail
                          ByteArrayOutputStream st = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                          thumbnailBm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, st);
                          byte[] byteArr = st.toByteArray();
                          ParseFile thumbFile = new ParseFile("thumb.jpg", byteArr);
                          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_THUMBNAIL, thumbFile);

                          vObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                              @Override
                              public void done(ParseException e) {
                                  if(e == null) {
                                      Log.i("log-", "THUMBNAIL SAVED! - SAVING VIDEO...");

                                      // Save video
                                      if (videoURI != null) {
                                          ParseFile videoFile = new ParseFile("video.mp4", convertVideoToBytes(videoURI));
                                          vObj.put(Configs.VIDEOS_VIDEO, videoFile);
                                          Log.i("log-", "VIDEO URI TO SUBMIT: " + videoURI);

                                          vObj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void done(ParseException e) {
                                                  if (e == null) {
                                                      pd.dismiss();
                                                      Log.i("log-", "SUCCESS! ");

                                                  // error on saving
                                                  } else {
                                                      Configs.simpleAlert(e.getMessage(), SubmitVideo.this);
                                                      pd.dismiss();
                                          }}});
                                      }


                                  // error on saving
                                  } else {
                                      Configs.simpleAlert(e.getMessage(), SubmitVideo.this);
                                      pd.dismiss();
                          }}});

                      } catch (FileNotFoundException err) { err.printStackTrace(); }


                  // error on saving
                  } else {
                      Configs.simpleAlert(e.getMessage(), SubmitVideo.this);
                      pd.dismiss();
          }}});
```

Anyone knows why that happens?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var api = new ParseServer({
...
    maxUploadSize: "300mb"
...});
```

Probably you will need to change your nginx/apache configuration to allow it.

Over nginx: `client_max_body_size 300M;`

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately I don't know what nginx is...if you mean this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/ No, i'm not using it

Comment: Can you change your server configuration? I think the max default size is 20mb

Comment: It seems Parse SDK for Android doesn't have file size limit anymore: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/pull/462/files

Comment: No parse SDK no, but your server yes : maxUploadSize - Max file size for uploads. Defaults to 20 MB.
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

Comment: All right, since I'm using Parse Server hosted on back4app it seems there's a file size limit on free accounts, accordingly to this link: https://www.quora.com/Does-Back4app-has-10MB-upload-limit-per-file

Comment: Nice, you can try this library to compress your images: https://github.com/Sunzxyong/Tiny

Comment: it's not about images but video files

Comment: anyway i've solved this issue by using Video Quality 0 in my java code, so video files mp4 have a lower size in MB

Answer (score 2):

The video may be too large to be uploaded at one go. 
You should use multiparts .. I had same problem while uploading high resolution images..  [Uploading High res images in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712197/uploading-high-res-images-in-android)
Modify this code for video

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I don't use PHP/MySQL but Parse Server SDK, so I don't think I can use that multipart code snippet in this case...

Comment: Are you using nginx?

Comment: I don't know what nginx is, sorry... if you mean this: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/ No, Im not using it